# How to extract matched dataframe in twang r package?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, dataset

I have used the "iptw" function in "twang" pacakage in R to do propensity score weighting. How can I extract my complete dataset after propensity score weighting?

Comment: According to `?iptw` this is what you get back a list containing of  (1) `psList` A list of ps objects with length equal to the number of time periods, (2) `estimand` The specified estimand, (3) `stop.methods` The stopping rules used to optimize iptw balance, (4) `nFits` The number of ps objects (i.e., the number of distinct time points), (5) `uniqueTimes` The unique times in the specified model.

Comment: The original dataset is the complete dataset. `iptw()` just estimates weights.